# How to bind collection of collection to a datagrid in Silverlight 4

Tags: data-binding, datagrid, silverlight-4.0

I have a collection of Departments, which has collection of Teachers and which has collection of all the classes they teach. I was able to create a collection of collection of collection from the data source. Now I want to bind the data to datagrid. What I want to bind is the classes taught in the school group by teachers by department.
What is the best way to do this and any pointers would be great.
Thanks.,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using third party control, where they support binding collection of collection. Both Telerik and Component One grid control support binding this kind of collection.